# Swift class not registering for notifications post from Objective C class using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I am rewriting a class in Swift that I did in Objective C, however, when I register my new Swift class as an observer it does not respond to notifications posted in another objective c class using NSNotificationCenter.

Code is the following:

Class A:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:REFRESH_UI object:nil];
```

Class B (objective-c):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshUI) name:REFRESH_UI object:nil];

- (void)refreshUI {
[self.tableView reloadData];}
```

Class B (swift)

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshUI", name:REFRESH_UI , object: nil)

func refreshUI() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Class B works fine when written in objective-c. What is wrong with my Swift code?

Comment: Does it work without the macro defining the notification name? I wonder if that's not evaluating to the right type in Swift.

Comment: I tried with and without using the macro already. Before it was @"RefreshUI", so I used "RefreshUI" in the name for the Swift method.

Comment: I just discovered a problem unrelated to this. So my code may actually be right.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran a quick test and there doesn't seem to be any special considerations for calling notifications from Obj-C to Swift.  This works fine:

AppDelegate:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refresh" object:nil];
    NSLog(@"Finished!");

});
```

Swift View:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSLog("loaded")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshUI", name:"refresh" , object: nil)
}


func refreshUI() {
    NSLog("Got the callback")
}
```

I would verify your REFRESH_UI is set on both correctly, and that your observer is added properly before you dispatch.

Comment: Yeah I believe the problem is stemming from elsewhere and Class A is no longer posting the notification when I use the Swift class for B.

Answer (score 3):

you have to define notification name in Objective c like that:

.h:

```
extern NSString * DidRefreshUINotification;
```

.m:

```
NSString *DidRefreshUINotification = @"DidRefreshUINotification"; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: DidRefreshUINotification object:nil];
```

and then in Swift-class:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(someSelector(_:)), name: .DidRefreshUI, object: nil)
```

DidRefreshUINotification in Objective C becomes just .DidRefreshUI in Swift, because it's stripped from the name as redundant.

There is a good post about adding notification observer in swift posted in Objective C class: 
http://inessential.com/2016/09/08/adding_a_notification_observer_in_swift_

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the error. It turned out to be a delegate issue from another class unrelated to this where I needed to fix my class B in Swift to handle the delegate. So the code I originally posted should work fine. I just switched to Swift yesterday so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: When I switched to Swift, I thought every problem I had was either Swift or interoperability. I spent about 3 hours missing the fact that I hadn't connected an outlet in storyboard.